# strange zsh filtering behavior

Tags: zsh, qualifiers

Doing:

`print -l ./somedir/**/*.{png,jpg}` gives expected listing of `png` and `jpg` files, and there are both types of them present, BUT

`print -l ./somedir/**/*.{png,jpg}(Lk+50)` does NOT list my `jpg` files greater than 50k, saying `no matches found ./somedir/**/*.png(Lk+50)`.

Why it stops on `png` here, not expanding on `jpg` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation, saying:

> Note that brace expansion is not part of filename generation (globbing); an expression such as */{foo,bar} is split into two separate words */foo and */bar before filename generation takes place. In particular, note that this is liable to produce a ‘no match’ error if either of the two expressions does not match; this is to be contrasted with */(foo|bar), which is treated as a single pattern but otherwise has similar effects.

I got to the conclusion that instead I have to write:

`print -l ./somedir/**/*.(png|jpg)(Lk+50)` ,to obtain the desired result.